# iOS: How to force openURL to open the browser, and not an app via universal link

Tags: ios, safari

I want to open a http/https link, and have it open in the browser -- not as an app deep link via a universal link for an installed app.

Things I've tried:

- openURL api: is launching universal links in app, not Safari
- SFSafariViewController: even that is auto-dismissing and launching universal links in another app.

Generally I think this is good for users, but I have a use case where staying in browser is necessary.

I can't control the link (so I can't just use URL scheme for native, and http for web). It needs to work with any http url, which may or may not be a universal link.

The system doesn't always open universal links (for example, if the user is on abc.com and taps a universal link abc.com/page/123, it stays in the web). I'd like to ensure that behaviour (staying in browser), programatically from native app code.

System default browser preferred, but safari-only solutions acceptable if that's all that's available.

Comment: Maybe you could experiment with adding a dummy query parameters to the link before you open it

Comment: Another workaround solution would be to put some kind of redirect page in between, to not trigger the universal link

Comment: @FrankieBaron Thanks for ideas. Looking at docs, query params won't work (at least not for all apps, and this needs to work for any link). A redirect likely would work, but has privacy implications. The redirecting domain could collect data and I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell that a link is universal URL or not, especially with URL redirection. The only way is to use custom browser that will not cooperate with iOS in redirecting user to apps.

1. If you have an appropriate external browser you can open a Share dialog using `UIActivityViewController`. Then a user will select the browser there.
2. Instead of `SFSafariViewController` use a custom browser engine inside of your app.